# Slanted sidebar layout

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have this slanted right-hand sidebar layout with CSS? The left side would be the main content where I assume the slanted sidebar layout could overlap the extra.

I've asked this question before but don't think a fixed pixel height border will do the trick to achieve the layout. Is there any other way? Something more flexible?

[image: slanted layout]

Comment: Please don't repost questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749872/css-slanted-sidebar-layout

Answer (score 1):

You can use diagonal linear gradient backgrounds with color stops to get that effect, e.g. `linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1e5799, #1e5799 50%, #207cca 50%, #207cca);`.  [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/vFsPF/)

Comment: hmm but the angle isn't right? It should be sharper vertical.

Comment: @user1420650 That's because I set the div height fairly short. It stretches from corner to corner.  You should be able to fix that fairly easily.

Comment: Here's an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/GBzRp/) of what I mean.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! This may work..

Comment: Also, I just discovered that it looks better if you set the stops to 49%/51% rather than 50/50.